# "not enough storage is available to process this command" after using the start command in a batch file with windows 7

Tags: memory, batch-file, command

I am creating a batch file that needs to open a second batch script in a separate cmd window. I can use all my code successfully if I use the "call" command instead of "start" but that doesn't launch the script in its own window. I have gotten this error many times in the past and its always related to the start command. I change how I do the process and all works well. Why is the start command causing this error and how can I fix it? Below is a sample of my code.

```
start "" /w "k:\Bundle Support files\record serial.cmd"
```

The second batch file opens and completes all tasks except the last one which is

```
goto :exit

:exit
```

I have changed the last command in the file several times and it always makes it through the entire batch but the last command that would finish that batch fails with the "not enough storage is available to process this command" error. This happens on multiple machines (varying hardware) and multiple OS's. I have attempted the IRPStackSize fix with no luck. Any suggestions as to why I am getting this error?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: use goto:goodbye and :goodbye as the labels. Exit might be handled as a reserved word

Comment: @rene I have had problems with it being reserved. End too on occasion. `goto goodbye` and `:goodbye` is a good suggestion. I usually use Fin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I think maybe I was not clear enough in my question. I am trying to figure out how the "start" command works and why when I use it the batch file that is "Started" will not finish NO MATTER what the last command. I will get the "not enough storage is available to process this command" error. I can use the start command successfully when starting an executable. The problem is using it with batch files.

Answer (score 20):

I have encountered a similar problem and the solution for me was rather strange. It appears that setting the title of the window to nothing ("") causes the error.

So, instead of

```
start "" /w "k:\Bundle Support files\record serial.cmd"
```

try

```
start "Placeholder Name" /w "k:\Bundle Support files\record serial.cmd"
```

I can't test whether this will work in your case (and I doubt it matters as you're long gone) but hopefully this will help someone experiencing any similar errors.

Comment: I am absolutely flabbergasted that this worked. What an awful red herring of an error message, Windows.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as well. And I used your solution to put in the title instead of empty "", it's working now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `goto :exit` with `goto :EOF`. Do not define the EOF label (it is predefined).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I think maybe I was not clear enough in my question. I am trying to figure out how the "start" command works and why when I use it the batch file that is "Started" will not finish NO MATTER what the last command. I will get the "not enough storage is available to process this command" error. I can use the start command successfully when starting an executable. The problem is using it with batch files.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the START command does when you launch a cmd.  If you ran START cmd  you wouldn't expect CMD to exit immediately - it stays there ready for use.  So you either CALL a cmd file and it will finish,  or you START a cmd,  and it will not finish - but you can make it finish by using the EXIT command.  The issue of the stack overflow was also answered correctly by SEIPIA - instead of using start ""  filename.cmd,    put something between the quotes to act as the title - that will prevent the stack overflow error.